# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x64: how to update Qt 5.10 from Qt 5.9.5?

Tags: ubuntu, qt

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x64 and I need to update my Qt 5 installation from v5.9.5 to v5.10.0, however when I issue the command

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

it gives me that

```
qt5-default is already at the latest versione (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1).
```

But obviously it's not true.
I've also tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

before, but without success.

What is wrong with those commands? I just need to install the core libs without the UI stuff (e.g. qtcreator).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the latest version of `qt5-default` package available from Ubuntu repositories [qt5-default (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qt5-default). To install the `5.10.x` version you should follow the instructions described on the official website : [Install Qt 5 on Ubuntu](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu)

The installation file can be downloaded from [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/).

The `5.10.0` version:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.0.run
```

The `5.10.1` version:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.1/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.1.run
```

to set qt 5.10 as default edit:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf
```

with the following line (replace $USER with your username):

```
/home/$USER/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin
/home/$USER/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib
```

then run:

```
qtchooser -print-env
qmake -v
```

.

Comment: ok, I installed the 5.10.0 with Qt Creator and Desktop gcc x64, but `qmake -v` still returns `QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
`

Comment: @1Z10 please add the output of `qtchooser -l`

Comment: I installed it and this is the output

`$ qtchooser -l
4
5
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5`

Comment: are there any good tips on installing this headless to the right place?

Answer (score 3):

Qt PPAs are maintained by Stephan Binner on Launchpad:

> https://launchpad.net/~beineri

Instructions for updating are listed within each PPA.

Answer (score 2):

I spent several weeks messing with a system level replacement of Qt 5.9.5 on Ubuntu Bionic and it didn't seem feasible without a backport.  The qtxxx.run file will install to /opt which is correct but ancillary and would require some environment variable and/or path override.  I built some programs against qt in /opt but they didn't work well just because everything wants to use system default.

System Qt is distributed in a wide array of folders that exist in parallel where the /opt is in a tree.  This magic appears to happen toward the end of the debuild/backportpackage type process where the rules makes changes to some of the paths stored in files to mesh with Ubuntu's structure.  I was unable to backport upstream versions because of chicken and the egg situations where cross-package dependencies fail even with the bootstrapped qmake.

Long story short, at least for me, best to stick with the Qt version that's part of the distro.  It is a core item that isn't meant to be either replaced or have multiple versions without very careful testing.

This was my experience but that doesn't mean it's fact.  I'd be pleased to hear if anyone had more success.